# How to run two projects in desired order in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

### **Background:**

I'm working on two projects in visual studio 2015 - one that produces a file (I'll call it "**Generator**"), and one that uses said file at runtime (I'll call it "**Consumer**").

### **What I want to do:**

I'm currently working on the file produced by **Generator**. In order to see how **Consumer** is affected after modification of **Generator** I have to:

1. Build and run **Generator**,
2. Switch startup project to **Consumer**,
3. Build and run **Consumer**,
4. Switch startup project back to **Generator**.

I'd like to have all of this done in a single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

### **What I've tried to do:**

In the solution properties->startup project there is an option called "Current selection" that makes this tedious process a bit faster, but this is only a partial solution.

I tried to use "multiple startup projects", but this approach isn't for me - it runs these projects simultaneously and I want **Consumer** to wait until **Generator** is done.

In my most succesful approach I made a .bat that runs **Generator** and added it to one of build steps in **Consumer** (doesn't really matter what step - I used "prebuild event"). I also added **Generator** to **Consumer**'s Build Dependencies. It works perfectly when I modify both **Generator** and **Consumer**. The problem appears when I modify **Generator** only - in such case build of **Consumer** doesn't trigger at all - which means that my bat file won't run **Generator** (I think that **Consumer** should be build, because dependent project was modifed).

### **What I don't want to do:**

My solution contains other projects, some of which take long time to build - I don't want to rebuild whole solution or any projects other that the two I was talking about.

Answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349311/visual-studio-delay-between-multiple-startup-projects) isn't for me - I don't want to alter **Consumer** only to simplify the building process, because **Generator** is merely a utility to create some file used in the main program (**Consumer**). On the other hand I don't mind adding some additional projects.

## To summarize:

If you know how to force project to be rebuild when it's dependency is out of date I'd be happy. If you know any other way to deal with my problem I'd be happy either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a *"how did I not think about it before?"* kind of solution:

Since I want to run **Generator** after it's modification I in fact want to run it after it's build. So instead of trying to run it in **Consumer**'s build i do this as **Generator**'s Post-build Event.